# UWP app on Xbox forgets webcam capability permissions

Tags: uwp, kinect, xbox-one

I'm working on a UWP application which uses the Kinect, and is destined to run on an Xbox One.

The application has the "webcam" capability declared in Package.appmanifest

Whenever I modify, rebuild, and redeploy the application to the Xbox, it seems to "forget" that I have previously granted the app permission to access the camera, and I have to do it again (Settings -> Account -> Privacy & online safety -> App privacy -> Camera).

Is there any way I can avoid this behaviour, and have the Xbox remember that I've given permission for this app to access the webcam? Without knowing how this works internally on the Xbox, it seems like I'm actually granting webcam access to just this exact version of my app, including the build date. Makes for a very slow development cycle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Whenever I modify, rebuild, and redeploy the application to the Xbox,
>   it seems to "forget" that I have previously granted the app permission
>   to access the camera

The setting should be bound to your **account** and app's **package family name**.

It seems to be working well on Xbox One, OS version **10.0.15063.1005**

Some items you need to check:

1. Ensure the OS version is the latest
2. Login a Live account or dev account, check it in **Dev Home**->**Test accounts**
3. Uncheck "**Uninstall and then re-install my package**" option in the project's Debug property page
   [image]
4. Check the permission in *Settings->Account->Privacy & online safety->App privacy->Camera->Choose which apps can use your Camera*

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I had the "Uninstall and then re-install my package" option checked on the Debug property page.
Also, for posterity: note that changing between Debug and Release configuration will cause the package to be uninstalled & reinstalled.